# iPhone create csv file for export on computer

Tags: iphone, file, csv, filesystems, export-to-csv

For testing purpose, I need to create logs in a CSV file in my iPhone application. I'm using Dave DeLong's CHCSVParser to create the CSV, but I don't know what path I should put when creating it to find it on my iPhone disk. I am using a FileBrowser app to go check the file straight from the device, but where to look at?

Also, I'm taking any advices for creating a CSV from the iPhone app and put it on a desktop computer, maybe you have other ways to do that...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put it in the *Documents* directory where you'd put anything else and enable document sharing while testing. Then you can get them straight from iTunes. You could also set up a simple web server that allows PUT and do HTTP PUT from your app. I'd probably do the second personally, especially just for testing.

To enable the file sharing, you need to add the [UIFileSharingEnabled](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW20) key to your Info.plist file and make sure it's set.

For more information on getting the *Documents* directory, please review the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), specifically the [File System](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW10) section, which you should have read by now.

Comment: Can you tell me how to enable the document sharing? I have no idea. I will use the first solution in my case, but I like both, thanks! And basically for the path, I would use `[[CHCSVWriter alloc] initWithCSVFile:@"/Documents/logs.csv" atomic:NO];` right?

Comment: @Dachmt - no, you need to get the documents directory as usual, you can't just write to /Documents, there's no such place. I'll edit the answer with a link for the property key you need to set for the file sharing.

Comment: Thank you @JasonCoco for all that! I'll take a look at it and update this post later.